# Why won't solscan display the metadata on this token?

Tags: metaplex, metadata, token-2022, solscan

Token account: https://solscan.io/token/FgR2pbKw6GAc1C4gj6wUDB4A7bxpyNKCbYQUXgcym5Y8?cluster=devnet
Add metadata: https://solscan.io/tx/Bdkgc5eLBBEwwKLbKbBPsPyvhwxFtmVXJUVA3kcTzgB6BUQkPk3RzSCFVFPvaRJbjm4ZNVu2EJzuvVRKUhccGj1?cluster=devnet
I copied the URI from another token to ensure the metadata format is correct. Also double checked that the metadata tab is identical to a working token. It displays correctly on Solana Explorer and Soflare but not on Solscan. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: This could be a solscan issue, so it might be best to reach out to them